# ReactJs Select tag not reflecting updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

i am having a select tag with value and onChange implemented, onChange fires a redux action and updates the state that is being used in options of select tag(so the component updates as the state updates)

I tried updating state normally and with a callback function.It doesn't help

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export class SelectDestination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={defaultval:''}
  }
  onSelectChange = event => {
    let val=event.target.value
    this.setState({defaultval:event.target.value},function(){this.props.onSelectChange(val)})


  };

  render() {


    let options = this.props.state.planets.filter((x)=>this.props.state.vistedDestinatons.indexOf(x.name)===-1);
    console.log(options)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          <select value={this.state.defaultval} onChange={this.onSelectChange} name="onselect">
            {options.map(x => (
              <option value={x.name.toString()}>{x.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    state: state
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSelectChange: payLoad =>
      dispatch({ type: "SELCT_CHNG", payload: payLoad })
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SelectDestination);
```

I expect that state must be reflected in select tag. When opened in react-dev-tools i can see the state updating.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.setState` is an asyncronous function. You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html). This generally means that you either have to result to callbacks or promises.